# How to get links inside links from webpage in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

How can i go to link  and get its  sub links and again get its sub sub links?like for example,

I want to go to

```
"https://stackoverflow.com"
```

then extract its links e.g

```
['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask', 'https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=bounties']
```

and again go to that sub link and extract those sub links links.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have solved problem by iterating and combining link again doing same thing. will post answer later.

Comment: Do a recursive function if the website which you want to scrape is a small one.. else for websites like stackoverflow, facebook, etc controlling should be done to stop the recursive funciton which can be hard. Or you could just stop when a certain level of the tree is reached.

Comment: I didnt used recursive. Actually i am working in different private link.

Comment: If you've got a start, please post what you've got, and ask a specific question about something that isn't working as you'd expect, or don't know how to approach. Then we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Scrapy for this. With Scrapy, you create a spider object which then is run by the Scrapy module.

First, to get all the links on a page, you can create a Selector object and find all of the hyperlink objects using the XPath:

```
hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
urls = hxs.xpath('*//a/@href').extract()
```

Since the hxs.xpath returns an iterable list of paths, you can just iterate over them directly without storing them in a variable. Also each URL found should be passed back into this function using the callback argument, allowing it to recursively find all the links within each URL found:

```
hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
for url in hxs.xpath('*//a/@href').extract():
    yield scrapy.http.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

Each path found might not contain the original URL, so that check has to be made:

```
    if not ( url.startswith('http://') or url.startswith('https://') ):
        url = "https://stackoverflow.com/" + url
```

Finally, the each URL can be passed to a different function to be parsed, in this case it's just printed:

```
    self.handle(url)
```

All of this put together in a full Spider object looks like this:

```
import scrapy

class StackSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "stackoverflow.com"
    # limit the scope to stackoverflow
    allowed_domains = ["stackoverflow.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://stackoverflow.com/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
        # extract all links from page
        for url in hxs.xpath('*//a/@href').extract():
            # make it a valid url
            if not ( url.startswith('http://') or url.startswith('https://') ):
                url = "https://stackoverflow.com/" + url
            # process the url
            self.handle(url)
            # recusively parse each url
            yield scrapy.http.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def handle(self, url):
        print(url)
```

And the spider would be run like this:

```
$ scrapy runspider spider.py > urls.txt
```

Also, keep in mind that running this code will get you rate limited from stack overflow. You might want to find a different target for testing, ideally a site that you're hosting yourself.

Comment: Hey , its working but i didnt understand it. Please edit with in simple example

Comment: Edited with step by step description for each part of the code :)